# How to remove the JSON array, brackets, key and value using replaceAll method?

Tags: json, rest, groovy, removeall, ready-api

I have following JSON as an output:-

```
def desiredJson = '{"count": 4, "max": "12", "min": 0, "details": [{"goBus": {"first": 12800, "second": 11900, "third": 12800},"goAir": {"first": 12800, "second": 11900, "third": 12800}, "gotTrain": {"first": 12800, "second": 11900},"sell": true, "darn": 2,"rate": [{ "busRate": 11900, "flag": false, "percent": 0}],}],}'
```

I want to remove "count" key and its value, remove

```
"goBus": {
    "first": 12800,
    "second": 11900,
    "third": 12800
},
```

And remove square brackets of "details" node.

I have tried below code to remove and replace as null:-

```
def slurper = new JsonSlurper();
def json = slurper.parse(file)

def newjson = JsonOutput.toJson(json).toString()

String j = "max"
newjson = newjson.replaceAll(""+ j +"", "")

log.info newjson
```

As an output, the max value is not getting removed. Or Is there any other way we can remove these all things from JSON.

Can anybody help me on this?

I have tried this also:-

```
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(desiredJson)
def njson =  json.details.goBus

def pjson = njson.remove()

log.info JsonOutput.toJson(pjson)
```

It is returning false.

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: In expected Output, I am getting only this "Key" = "max" removed that too without quotes.. Like this :- "": "12".. But the solution @cfrick has given is correct.. But it is not removing these "goBus": {
    "first": 12800,
    "second": 11900,
    "third": 12800
}, with the same approach.

Comment: It would help if you can put exact desired json than explanation.

Comment: I have added it @rao

Comment: No, I just want to remove this goBus object from the desiredJson. @nitin

Comment: I do not see the requested info though you say added it. Asking the expected result explicitly because, you mentioned to remove '['. So, appreciate it if you can show the expected json.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There usually is no reason to that with string replacements -- it has just to much potential to mess something up.  You can just modify the map before writing it back as JSON.  E.g.:

```
import groovy.json.*

def jsonStr = '{"a": 1, "b": [{"c": 3, "d": 4}]}}'
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonStr)
// XXX: first "de-array" `b`
json.b = json.b.first()
// next remove `c` from it
json.b.remove('c')
println JsonOutput.toJson(json)
// => {"a":1,"b":{"d":4}}
```

#### edit:

OP also wants to get rid of the array, altough this messes with the naming and only works if there is at least one element (see comments)

Comment: This is fine. but in my case, I want to remove  "goBus": {
        "first": 12800,
        "second": 11900,
        "third": 12800
    }, which is inside "details" array node.. How should I process for this?

Comment: @Rao - it is working here with cfrick code.. But the goBus object is not getting removed with the same approach.

Comment: I missed the array in question.  You have to use an explicit spread operator do your work on each element.

Comment: Thanks, I had resolved it.. I have asked about removing the square bracket of "rate" array from the desiredJson.. else removing the square bracket for "b" array would suffice. Can we remove it?

Comment: This makes only sense, if there only ever to be just one `details`, which does not sound like it (plural). So you can do with a rule like "always the first".  e.g. `json.details = json.details.first()`

Comment: Sorry, I am not getting.. Is this what you are suggesting to remove square bracket "[ ]" @cfrick

Comment: Yes, this will replace the array on `details` with just the first element in `details`. But I find this very misleading.  I'd rather add `detail` and and then delete `details`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162604/discussion-between-avidcoder-and-cfrick).

Answer (score 2):

This is the working solution with your desired output

Working code here [Working example](https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5095068029419520)

```
import groovy.json.* 
def jsonStr = '''{
"count": 4,
"max": "12",
"min": 0,
"details": [{
    "goBus": {
        "first": 12800,
        "second": 11900,
        "third": 12800
    },
    "goAir": {
        "first": 12800,
        "second": 11900,
        "third": 12800
    },
    "gotTrain": {
        "first": 12800,
        "second": 11900,
        "third": 12800,
        "fourth": 13000
    },
    "sell": true,
    "darn": 2,
    "rate": [{
        "busRate": 11900,
        "flag": false,
        "percent": 0
        }]
    }]
}'''

def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonStr) 
json.details[0].remove('goBus') 
println JsonOutput.toJson(json) ​
```

Comment: That's perfect @Nitin, Is there anyway, I could make it dynamic.. Say, If you have goBus sometimes at other position.. In that case, what would you suggest.

Comment: Here, the 0th position will be fine if you don't have the nested objects (which you want to remove) inside "details", keep json structure consistent if possible.